# Вешать по нескольку событий

Tags: javascript

```
EventTarget.prototype.add = (_ => {
    //Array.isArray(ff)
    return function() {
        EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
        return this;
    }
})();

i.add(this.desktop ? 'mouseenter' : 'touchstart', e => {});
```

Либо одно, либо другое вешаю. На сколько мне известно, возможно к сенсорному монитору, к примеру планшету, подключить мышь. Либо у ноутбука, пк, сенсорный монитор. И в данном случаи необходимо вешать оба прослушивателя.

Вопрос в том, как лучше это сделать. Возможно указывать, события в качестве массива и добавлять сразу, не перебирая их через цикл.

И как в данном случаи лучше сделать это?

**Что если так писать**

```
class Target {
    constructor(val) {
        this.el = val
    }
    add(e, f) {
        e.forEach(i => this.el.addEventListener(i, f));
        return this

    }
}
new Target(i).add(['mouseenter', 'touchstart'], t => {

    console.log(t)

}).add(['mouseleave', 'touchend'], t => {

    console.log(t)

});
```

Comment: за раз можно указать только один тип события, поэтому без цикла не обойтись

Comment: Возможно ли дописать 'EventTarget.prototype.add',  с циклом?

Comment: а какая разница в какой функции будет цикл?

Comment: Синтаксис удобный, было бы здорово если стало возможным прописывать так

Comment: i.add([ 'mouseenter' , 'touchstart'], e => {});

Comment: мне кажется это не сильно отличается от `add(i, [ 'mouseenter' , 'touchstart'], e => {})`

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов В добавок скажу, что отвыкайте лезть в `prototype` (особенно у встроенных объектов) это может привести к абсолютно неожижданным результатам в будущем как уже история показывала это нам не раз. Лучше пишите свои ф-ии - это не так страшно и намного безопаснее

Comment: Хорошо, а что если так писать, классом. Дополнил вопрос, есть ли какой негативный опыт в этом?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю add(i, [ 'mouseenter' , 'touchstart'], e => {}).add(i, [ 'mouseenter' , 'touchstart'], e => {})

Comment: Разве это будет работать, и переменную i каждый раз придется передавать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с классами:

```js
class Target {
  constructor(query) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(query);
  }
  
  addEvent(eventName, handler) {
    this.el?.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
    return this;
  }
  
  addEvents(eventsNames, handler) {
    eventsNames.forEach(eventName => this.addEvent(eventName, handler));
    return this;
  }
}

const exampleDiv = new Target('#example')
  .addEvent('mouseover', () => console.log('Hover not click'))
  .addEvents(['click', 'dblclick'], (e) => {
    console.log(`You just ${e.type}ed me`);
  });
```

```html
<div id="example">Click or doubleclik or hover</div>
```

Как устанваливать значение для `this.el` решайте сами, мне мой способ (через селелктор) показался удобнее потому так написал, можете передавать сразу нужный элемент, если вам так удобнее